# Why is cargo update updating the lock file

Tags: rust-cargo

I don't manage to understand what `cargo update` do and I find the doc inconsistent.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-update.html

Actually it says:

- "name: Update dependencies as recorded in the local lock file" from which I guess that cargo.lock is just **read from**
- "description: This command will update dependencies in the Cargo.lock file to the latest version. If the Cargo.lock file does not exist, it will be created with the latest available versions." from which I guess that it will **write** the Cargo.lock. but how, according to which rules, I'm not sure about

Answer (score 1):

The documentation needs to be updated. `cargo update` will update minor and patch versions of your dependencies inside `Cargo.lock`, i.e. update everything without introducing breaking changes as long as your dependencies adhere to [Cargo's semver compatibility](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#semver-compatibility).

There is also `cargo upgrade` which will upgrade dependencies in `Cargo.toml`. It can be instructed to upgrade even major versions and then you might have to fix some breaking changes.

Comment: just a note that cargo doesn't fully understand semver and it will update packages with major version 0. cargo update will introduce breaking changes if any dep of a dep of a dep has major version 0. If it does understand semver, then saying cargo update will not introduce breaking changes is not correct.

Comment: Yes, Cargo also defined that versions 0.x.y are compatible with 0.x.z which is not defined by semver itself. I added a link but this seems to be out of scope of the question so I'd leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with rust, but I have used a number of package managers.

Typically you have three ways to go about it:

1. Something like `cargo install` which uses the lock file directly without change to install dependencies. This can however fail in the case of depency conflicts.
2. Something like `cargo update` which would update all dependines to try to use the newest versions. This is rarely recommended as it can break existing apps very easily. Only use it if you have a very good test suite or are willing to do a lot of manual testing.
3. Something like `cargo update xyz` to update specific dependencies (`xyz` in this case). This is typically the recommended way to go and you should try to minimize the number of dependencies you update this way, usually you can do something like `cargo update abc pqr xyz` to update those three dependencies. This is generally the recommended way to go.

Basically, you run #1 if it fails, it will say which dependencies
have issues then you run `cargo update ...` on those specific
dependencies.